# Is there Full solution to cache busting using Gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, build, gulp

Things it needs to do minimum:

1. Watch for file changes and update files in `dist/**` like so `icon.png`, `abc.css`, `main.js` to `icon1783.png`, `abc84848.css`, `main7272.js`.
2. Update source map names accordingly. the name of sourcemap should be same as js file, as hash of source map is going to be different from minified js file.
3. Finally, Somehow update the references in views somehow. For my need, update pug templates under `views/**` with correct references. for all (js|css|img).

Answer (score 2):

The module [gulp-hash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-hash) could serve your needs. It can add a hash to your file names and create a manifest JSON file that maps your original file to the hashed version. You then reference this manifest JSON file to serve the hashed version of your files.

Here is an example of a Gulpfile that watches for JavaScript changes, minifies the file, versions it with a hash, maps it in a JSON file, and removes the old outdated version:

```
import gulp   from 'gulp';
import {exec} from 'child_process';
import hash   from 'gulp-hash';
import uglify from 'gulp-uglify';

// Minifies main.js
gulp.task('script', () => {
  exec('rm dist/scripts/main-*.min.js') // Deletes old hashed app JS file
  return gulp
    .src('dis/scripts/main.js') // Source file
    .pipe(uglify()) // Minifies the file
    .pipe(hash({ template: '<%= name %>-<%= hash %>.min<%= ext %>' })) // Adds randomly generated hash to JS file name
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts/`)) // Adds hashed JS file to destination dir
    .pipe(hash.manifest('hashed-assets.json')) // Writes manifest JSON file
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dist/)); // Adds manifest some destination dir
});

// Watch main.js file for changes
gulp.task('watch', () => {
  gulp.watch('dist/scripts/main.js', ['script']);
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['script', 'watch']);
```

Now you'll have a `main.js` and `main-87362721.min.js` in your `dist/scripts/` folder. In your `dist/` folder you'll also have `hashed-assets.json` which will look like this:

```
{"main.js":"main-87362721.min.js"}
```

When you make a change to `main.js`, the watch task will notice that you've changed the file and will trigger the script task.

That's how you do #1 and #2 in your question. #3 I'll have to leave for someone that is familiar with Pug.js, but the general goal is to reference the `hashed-assets.json` file and iterate over each key to serve its value.